# how to convert this type of array into list?

Tags: php, arrays, list, codeigniter

I am trying to insert data into highcharts in codeigniter. Highcharts want the data to be a list like this [313, 985, 5238, 1237].

But from my query I got this result from var_dump($revenue):

```
array(14) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { ["data"]=> string(7) "2838475" } 
    [1]=> array(1) { ["data"]=> string(8) "136246.8" } 
    [2]=> array(1) { ["data"]=> string(7) "3406170" } 
    [3]=> array(1) { ["data"]=> string(9) "3655955.8" } 
    [4]=> array(1) { ["data"]=> string(7) "4132820" } 
    [5]=> array(1) { ["data"]=> string(7) "4087404" } 
    [6]=> array(1) { ["data"]=> string(9) "1271636.8" } 
    [7]=> array(1) { ["data"]=> string(8) "499571.6" } 
    [8]=> array(1) { ["data"]=> string(7) "9764354" } 
    [9]=> array(1) { ["data"]=> string(10) "713933.232" } 
    [10]=> array(1) { ["data"]=> string(10) "714614.466" } 
    [11]=> array(1) { ["data"]=> string(9) "2827121.1" } 
    [12]=> array(1) { ["data"]=> string(9) "1793916.2" } 
    [13]=> array(1) { ["data"]=> string(9) "2066409.8" } 
}

$tanggal = array();
$revenue = array();
$top5 = array();
$data_top5 = $this->db->get_where('top_five_kfa', array('kfa' => 'Aceh', 'produk' => 'Fituno'))->result();
foreach ($data_top5 as $key => $value){
    $tanggal[$key]['category'] = $value->tanggal;
    $revenue[$key]['data'] = $value->revenue;
    $top5[$key]['data'] = $value->top5;
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
[2838475, 136246.8, 3406170, 3655955.8, 4132819.6, 4087404, 
1271636.8, 499571.6, 9764354, 713933.232, 714614.466, 
2827121.1, 1793916.2, 2066409.8]
```

Any sugestion how? or any reference? I get stuck on this for a week

Comment: [array_column](http://php.net/array_column). Or just change `$revenue[$key]['data']` to `$revenue[]`

Comment: If you're also asking how to make it with the `[ ]` ready for highcharts, use [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$revenue[$key]['data'] = $value->revenue;` *use* `$revenue[] = $value->revenue;`

`echo json_encode($revenue);` will provide array list as like you expected.